# The difference between $\forall x[R(x) \rightarrow P(x)]$ and $\forall x[R(x)\wedge P(x)]$.

Tags: predicate-logic

Apparently, it is a common mistake to write $\forall x[R(x) \rightarrow P(x)]$ instead of $\forall x[R(x)\wedge P(x)]$ in some cases, however I can't seem to find the difference between the two.

I did some research in ProofWiki and a Discrete Mathematics book, but I couldn't find this specific difference explained.

Could you please explain it to me and give some examples on when to use one and when to use the other?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try using the tableau method. It's handy for this sort of thing.

Comment: $p\rightarrow q$ is equivalent to $\neg p\vee q$ that is: $p$ is not true or $q$ is true. $p\wedge q$ is: $p$ is true and $q$ is true. I should say that a difference between them is obvious.

Comment: In the first case, if $R$ is true then also $P$ is true. But it is possible to have $P$ true without $R$. But in the second case, you must have both true to have the statement true.

Comment: This mistake may be because in English, one sometimes says "this and that" to mean this causes that.

Comment: “If I am the best then I am the best” is true but does not imply that I am the best.

Comment: In fact, have you tried $P=R$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the difference between

1. "anyone who gets a perfect score on the quiz will receive a cookie," and
2. "everyone gets a perfect score on the quiz and will receive a cookie."

It's a bit tricky to translate number 1 from colloquial language into first-order logic, but when you do, it says $\forall x\,(Q(x) \to C(x))$ where $Q(x)$ means "$x$ gets a perfect score on the quiz" and $C(x)$ means "$x$ will receive a cookie."

Comment: This made sense, thank you!

Comment: @borg123 You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Try with the following basic, intuitive definitions:

$$x\in\Bbb Z=\text{the set of integer numbers}\;,\;\;R(x):=x\;\text{is a prime number}\;,\;$$

$$P(x):=x\;\text{not divisible by}\;4$$

Then you try to explain the difference between "For any integer $\;x\;$ , if $\;x\;$ is a prime number then is is undivisible by four" and "For any integer $\;x\;$ , $\;x\;$ is both prime and undivisible by four".

Answer (score 3):

Assume $[\forall x[Rx\to Px]]\leftrightarrow [\forall x[Rx\wedge Px]]$ and suppose $ \forall x[Rx\to Px] $. Then $ \forall x[Rx\wedge Px] $. Instantiate with $a$ for $x$. Now $Ra\to Pa$ and $Ra$, $Pa$. But then $\neg Ra$ is an option, a contradiction.

You can see these things clearly with tableaux.

[image: Tableau]

Comment: @borg123: I recommend S.G. Simpson's Mathematical Logic lecture notes  for learning how to construct tableaux.